# Azure Devops Data Warehouse Deployment Error SQL72031: This deployment may encounter errors during execution

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, azure-synapse

*** Verification of the deployment plan failed.
Error SQL72031: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [localuser] are blocked by [db_datareader]'s dependency in the target database.

I tried to use Azure Devops to deploy to Production Azure Data warehouse, but I am getting the above error.

Please help!

Comment: Hi @burberry398, How are thing going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please try it, and if you have any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT thank you, I am able to solve the problem!

Comment: Hi @burberry398, Glad to hear that you solve the problem. If possible, could you please post an answer as the summary of the reason and solution for the problem? This may be very helpful to other people who have the similar problems when they are looking for an answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is ticket about the similar problem:
[SSDT Publish errors on Creating Publish Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618386/ssdt-publish-errors-on-creating-publish-preview)

As the explanation, your sqlproj may be not included in a stored procedure in the target database that references a table that would be altered by deploying your sqlproj.

You can try to add the stored procedure from the target database to your sqlproj.

You also can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) to try deploying Azure SQL Data Warehouse to the Azure SQL Server on your local machine.

And here also is a similar case as reference: [Error while Updating .mdf database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009365/error-while-updating-mdf-database)